# Need flag help for over zealous user!

Tags: discussion, specific-question, down-votes

I just got a down-vote for a completely legitimate answer and now I can't flag it so I might get my rep points back. Can someone up-vote me? I should only need 1 point on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you are referring to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832236/creating-a-dropdown-with-customized-options/4347728#4347728) ... I'm sure you meant well, but it can be argued @meagar has a point. Also, downvotes can't be flagged or appealed, as every community member is free to upvote and downvote as they please.

I wouldn't worry too much about it - you can give a more specific answer if you want to; you can also let it stand, or delete it.

If you answer questions conscisely and correctly, you will earn a lot more reputation in a short time span.

Comment: I'm not really worried about the rep it just seemed needless to down vote an answer. I guess I should just tread lightly. People around here stomp you for the littles things

Comment: @nuclear you're taking this downvoting business the wrong way: It's not a personal attack. (Well it sometimes can be, but not in your case.) SO has a very high standard of conscise answers, and *everyone* gets downvoted from time to time if somebody thinks you have deviated from that standard. I have 4,611 answers under my belt, I'm on page 1, and still get downvoted if I get something wrong - and that's great! It ensures a high standard of quality and good answers. Just shrug it off, continue giving answers in areas you know about, and positive feedback is sure to follow.

Comment: @nuclearpro: You should be thankful that one of the people downvoting you at least left a comment explaining why, which you *could* take to heart by editing your answer to make it more useful. Many downvoters won't leave a message, so there's no way to know what they don't like about your answer.

Comment: yes he did he said my answer didn't give much information. he also said that the poster didn't give much information.. i was answering based on the question that had little detail. I'm not worried about the votedown thing if I was i would have deleated my post which has now been voted down more times.

Comment: the system in place takes away privlages that I want. I'm really not taking this personally I just thought it was a rediculus thing to do. and I tend to see that more and more on stack. I think mods should take a look. users very well may be driving off new comers. Thats it, and a little sense of humor never killed anyone. Ive been laughing this whole time

Comment: @nuclearpro this is an issue only in the very onset of your activity on SO. Gain a few upvotes, and you will have all the privileges you need and none of this will matter.

Comment: i agree. I'm dumbfounded by the lack of personality in some of the users. but alas I'm low man on the totem pole and I know my place. Sitting in the corner with the dunce hat on. hehe

Comment: @nuclearpro: "I'm dumbfounded by the lack of personality in some of the users." Hah! Hahahaha!! Hahahahahahahaha! Hahah. Hah.

Answer (score 6):

**No.**

If it was up to each user what rank their answers should have, and what number appears beside their name, the ranks and numbers would be meaningless. Review your answer with a critical eye, fix any problems you find, and rely on others to give it the rank (and you the rep) deserved.

Comment: ok forget it i come to the community for help and AGAIN I get bashed. I'll keep my mouth shut from now on and not try to help anyone for fear that ill lose more privileges .. oh yeah isn't that the point of this community, an open environment to share ideas?

Comment: @nuclearpro: no, it's not. Meta is a support / discussion site for Stack Overflow - begging for up-votes was never intended as a valid use-case.

Comment: @nuclear, nowhere in Shogs answer does he bash you. Maybe you need to stop being so sensitive and stop taking downvotes so personally. And if it's an open environment to share ideas, shouldn't people be able to disagree with your ideas? As in... downvoting?

Comment: again... gaffer tape implemented. No argument here I just cant play with the big boys.

Comment: @nuclear If one downvote gives you this much trouble, you are indeed  too thin skinned to participate in Stack Overflow. (And most other sites on the Internet, for that matter. SO is a *very* nice and civil place.)

Comment: the downvote took away my privlage to flag so the admins could take a look. thats it i could care less about my rep. i just think people get bashed to frequently on this forum. thats it. no thin skin, no hard feelings just a request.

Comment: @nuclearpro: asking an admin for help *is* a valid use of Meta... I don't think your situation merits any action, but I wouldn't discourage you from asking. Just don't ask for votes...

Comment: Does flagging for mod attention even require rep? I thought it was just spam/offensive, but I'm not positive. (Mods probably aren't going to do anything either way, I'm just curious)

Comment: @Michael Requires 15 reputation, just like the other flags.

Comment: @Rejoice "SO is a very nice and civil place." ... tell that to the guy voting me down to nothing. hehehe

Comment: @nuclearpro: as several people have now told you, taking down-votes personally is a recipe for unhappiness...

Comment: and as ive told many here.. im not taking it personally. i thought it was rediculus and im still laughing as my rep falls to 8 at the moment. Have some sense of humor.

Comment: from the ask a question faq...

Comment: Keep an open mind The answer to your question may not always be the one you wanted, but that doesn't mean it is wrong. A lot of what we do is as much an art as a science, so a conclusive answer isn't always possible. When in doubt, ask people to cite their sources, or to explain how/where they learned something. Even if we don't agree with you, or tell you exactly what you wanted to hear, remember – we're just trying to help

Comment: @nuclearpro You cannot go below 1 rep.