# Bounty place on another's question about to expire

Tags: discussion, support, bounties, expired-bounty

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

EDITED

I have placed a bounty on someone else's question. It has received 12 up-votes and 4 favorites, but still no answers.

[How do I deploy using MSDeploy in Team Build 2010 using the WMSVC service and NTLM authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7639597/how-do-i-deploy-using-msdeploy-in-team-build-2010-using-the-wmsvc-service-and-nt)

The bounty expires in 3 days.

What are my options if no answers are provided when the expiration occurs? Or what if someone sneaks in with a retarded zero-vote answer to snag the bounty.

Comment: Could you link the question? (I know we can find it in your profile, but that would make it easier to find)

Comment: I've provided the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Or what if someone sneaks in with a retarded zero-vote answer to snag the bounty.

From the [Unofficial FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work):

> The criteria for an answer to be eligible for automatic awarding are
>   as follows:
>
> - The answer must be given after the bounty was started
> - The answer must have a score of at least +2

If you suspect a really poor answer got the required +2 through shady voting, downvote as necessary and feel free to flag for moderator attention and succinctly describe the problem in the description box. Moderators do seek out [sock puppets](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71501/possible-cheating-via-sock-puppet-account), so if you suspect you see it happening, say something.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, 3 days out is not "about to expire," there is a lot more action on bountied questions in the last day and even the last couple hours of the bounty, as it works its way up the "featured" list.

Yes, your 50 pts are gone no matter what. "Unresolved" bounties are lost; see here: [What happens if there are no answers to a bounty question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9902/172958)

If someone posts a non-answer just for the bounty, flag it and I'm sure the mods will delete it (deleted questions aren't eligible for bounty).  <strike>If you get an inadequate answer, either you can let it take the bounty as it was the best advice offered, or you can answer your own question and award that the bounty (you won't get the rep back, but you will prevent it from being automatically awarded to an insufficient answer).</strike> (apparently this was recently removed)