# Earning more reputation by cheating is much easier?

Tags: discussion, reputation, moderators

First I would like to clarify some points:

- I'm raising an issue (reporting a bug) about the Stack Overflow politics for reputation.
- I'm not interested in being a member of Stack Overflow (never was, it's just not for me). The only reason I registered an account was to vote. Because I observed that there is something wrong with many reviews.
- My recent answer on Stack Overflow was partially meant as a final experience to check reputation reliability

### Issue Summary

Average reviews are not honest in general because people who vote are the same people who answer and the same people who want to get the best reputation ever and they care more about the author than the content. Hence, it's much easier to cheat and the system is not really that good at detecting serial voting, sock puppetry or unreasonable votes.

### Observation

When a new user starts answering questions, no matter how good their answers are, they are not welcome at all. (I observed that before being a member) Older users try to prevent a new competitor from existing by all possible methods including but not limited to:

- Voting down for good answers
- Commenting by any possible enhancement suggestions in a way that implicitly says (wrongfully) that the answer is wrong and useless
- Fabricating any possible bugs that actually do not exist
- Threatening

### Related links

[Six simple tips to get Stack Overflow reputation fast](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17204)

[Upvoting based on celebrity, too many upvotes ("excessive rep slurping")](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752)

[Possible cheating via sock-puppet account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71501)

My answers on Stack Overflow could also support my issue if reviewed honestly by a C/C++ developer. Specially [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40542850/how-do-i-get-output-of-command-in-c/40545268#40545268) with -3 rating.

Note: If the community webmasters/moderators are interested in fixing this issue, I wouldn't mind spending more time to help finding a solution.

Comment: If they downvoted a lot of your posts, it will be detected as serial voting and get reversed. If you suspect sock-puppetry, you can flag  a post for moderator attention and write what you suspect. Coming to meta with such a frustrated attitude is not the way to go.

Comment: noting was detected and I assume this person is a moderator

Comment: then what is meta for?

Comment: Meta is to discuss general site policies. Matters like this are serious and should be kept private. Mods already deal with a lot of sock-puppetry everyday, and none of that info is revealed on meta. That said, if that person is a moderator, I can fully assure you that you're wrong and no one is stalking you. Furthermore, how can you know who downvoted?

Comment: You seem a bit heated. I understand the frustration that comes with getting a downvote, but you should just shrug it off. No one is forcing you to be here. Come back when you feel it's fun again, whenever that may be.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I handle possible revenge downvotes?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106704/how-should-i-handle-possible-revenge-downvotes)

Comment: I'm assuming this has to do with your Stack Overflow account. If so, as a moderator I don't see an obvious pattern of targeted voting, but I do notice that one person has left multiple comments that are critical of your posts. I should note that this person is not a moderator, and in fact has had multiple comments deleted by moderators. I see no evidence of sock puppetry here, or anywhere around this other person, assuming they were the one who voted. If this was this one person, they did leave comments explaining why they thought there were problems with each of these posts.

Comment: Voting content is designed to be helpful, a downvote indicates there is a problem with your question, unless you vote on content because of the author who wrote them its helpful.  Step back for a minute, for one moment consider, that your questions actually can be improved.  Once you do you should improve your questions

Comment: FIY, you mention Stack Overflow a lot—this site is about the entire Stack Exchange network, any questions specific to Stack Overflow should be posted to meta.stackoverflow.com (not saying you should move the question, just letting you know)

Comment: I doubt your last two answers on SO are simply valid. On at least one you have been given plenty of feedback which I think is valid. I'm not sure why you're not considering to address the issues raised and instead post and edit here on meta.

Comment: You mean [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40542850/how-do-i-get-output-of-command-in-c/40545268#40545268) one? actually I was trying to avoid accusing specific users by names... but since it's already clear, that's where the last fight started between me and **Cheers and hth. - Alf**..  by this invalid feedback.  And please (if you don't mind) check by your self if my extremely clear and simple code has UB the rest of the feed back is opinion based.

Comment: And by the way, many comments was removed by a mod and that's not how the conversation was and the date/time is not correct

Comment: Oh sorry! @rene  I missed that you have no experience on C or C++!......I'm not judging you but I'm asking you to think again about the way you judge.

Comment: I would think again about the way you judge.

Comment: Ok, I like constructive criticism...  So would you clarify what you mean please? And I'm not an enemy!

Comment: But I care too much about honesty. That's why I don't have too much remaining respect to many people on this community. And that's why I wasted my time and effort considering less than 1% possibility that someone might care.

Comment: is my post less offensive now? You are welcome to criticize me as long as you're not just trying to make fun of me.

Comment: Please forgive me @rene ! .. I actually missed the **view more** link in the tags section of your profile.....  XD So embarrassing!

Answer (score 16):

Lets start with the "you can't know who have downvoted you" line, which always seems to be necessary to come up with.

That said, there is nothing we can do for you. We all feel very sorry if it indeed went the way you described. Since we don't have access to voting information there are some things you have to do:

- Wait. Yes, indeed. For at least a day. The automatic serial voting detection script will run every night and it will reverse downvotes if it detects foul play.
- If that didn't help, you can flag one of your posts and ask a moderator to investigate what happened. Show what proof you have and how things went down. Then wait for a little longer for the moderator to handle your flag. They have lots of flags to handle and often they have to contact the SE team to do some digging, so they are working for you, but you need a little patience. Last, you need to accept the decision they make. Sometimes it feels like foul play, but nothing actually happened. Sometimes it is all a bunch of coincidence.

And please don't let one or more downvotes discourage you. We have all been there and it feels unfair sometimes, but hey, there is a lot more to enjoy here.